# Minimizing $\frac{1-\int_{1-\int_{0}^1 F(r)dr }^1 F(t) dt }{1-\int_{0}^1 F(t)^2 dt}$ for increasing function subject to $F(0)=0, F(1)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, mathematica, approximate-integration, weierstrass-approximation

Let $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be an increasing function with $F(0)=0, F(1)=1$. Define $A(x)=1-\int_{x}^1 F(t) dt$. I am trying to **approximately** minimize the following ratio across all $F$ (i.e find a lower bound on the ratio).

$$\frac{A(A(0))}{1-\int_{0}^1 F(t)^2 dt} = \frac{1-\int_{1-\int_{0}^1 F(r)dr }^1  F(t) dt }{1-\int_{0}^1 F(t)^2 dt}$$

My attempt:

I tried approximating $F$ using Stone–Weierstrass theorem: Letting $f_i = F(\frac{i}{5})$, then

$$F(x) \approx \sum_{i=0}^5 f_i {5 \choose i}x^i (1-x)^{5-i}$$

Then I evaluated the ratio (on Mathematica), and threw that into an optimizer subject to $f_0=0, f_5=1$ and $f_i \leq f_{i+1}$ constraints. The minimum seems to be $\approx 0.930147$. Replacing $5$ with $8$ above gets $\approx 0.917706$

However, I don't see how to generalize this for higher powers analytically using Bernstein polynomials.

Comment: I found an $F$ that yields the approximation $\approx 0.9128$

Comment: Would you take an answer with $F:(0,1) \to (0,1)$ where $\lim_{t \to 0} F(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t \to 1} F(t)=1.$?

Comment: Fix $a=\int_0^1 F$,and  $\int_{1-a}F=b$. Then you want to minimize the integral of $F^2$, so your function should be constant on $[0,1-a]$ and $[1-a,1]$ (note that the boundary conditions may be violated but the increasing property and the inequality $0\le F\le 1$ remain; restoring the boundary conditions will force you to change $F$ on a set of arbitrarily small measure, so $\min$ may be actually $\inf$) This results in the minimization of a rational function of two arguments with obvious constraints. Shouldn't be a rocket science...

Comment: Following **fedja**'s idea, the minimizer of the ratio given the constraint $\int_{0}^{1}F(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=a$ and $\int_{1-a}^{1}F(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=b$ takes the form $$F(t)=\frac{a-b}{1-a}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1-a)}(t)+\frac{b}{a}\mathbf{1}_{[1-a,1]}(t)$$ where $a^2<b<a$. Plugging this to the ratio and then allowing $b$ to vary, the ratio is minimized at $b=1-(1-a)\sqrt{1+a}$, yielding $$\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}\right).$$ Therefore the infimum is achieved by letting $a\to1^-$:$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx0.853553$$

Comment: @fedja and Sangchul Lee Thanks!

Comment: @SangchulLee or fedja, if you want to move this to an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Wow I should probably delete my answer lol - not as good as what was achieved in the comments

Comment: @geocalc33 I would leave it, it's a nice addition. Thanks!

Comment: Sure - thanks @AspiringMat!

Comment: Glad it helped. I can move my comment to an answer, but before that, let me wait to see if fedja wants to write down his/her own one. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will use a function $F:(0,1) \to (0,1)$ where $\lim_{t \to 0^+} F(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t \to 1^-} F(t)=1.$

Let $F_r(t)=e^{\frac{1/r}{\log t}}$ where you'd like to minimize the following ratio over $r$:

$$E(r)= \frac{1-\int_{1-\frac{2K_1\big(\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}}\big)}{\sqrt{r}}}^1e^{\frac{1/r}{\log t}}dt}{1-\frac{\sqrt{2}K_1\big( \sqrt{\frac{2}{r}} \big)}{\sqrt{r}}} $$

We're looking for $\text{min}(E(r))\approx E(85) \approx 0.911078522836.$ (this minimum was found numerically using Mathematica).

Here $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

This may not be the minimum value across any choice of $F$ but it improves the minimum in your post and I hope it helps.

Note that I've suppressed some calculations in the expression $E(r)$ to make it more concise. I can add in all of the steps if needed.